# c# solution architecture for signal-r and angular

Tags: c#, architecture, signalr

I would like to build a c# spa application using angular with real-time messaging signal-r. The signal-r should read the data continuously from a data source and publish the updated data to the user and store the data in a database as well. It should also enable the chatting of the users.The expected number of users is around a hundred.

For such application what should be the best architectural structure of the solution? Should I implement two (three?) projects, e.g. one for the web app and the other for the signal-r, running as two applications? Then, in this case, how can I do the messaging between the applications? Or should I implement a single project for all of these? It would be best if you can provide the pros and cons of these alternatives or provide any other option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with one project.

For 100 simultaneous users, you aren't even *close* to worried about load. Any simple hosting plan would take care of it easily. If you get more, ASP.NET and SignalR work just fine behind a load balancer (though certain operations can get more complicated).

A properly architected application won't be difficult to split into multiple processes in the future if it ever came to that, and doing so now is just adding mounds of complexity for no appreciable benefit. This goes double since it sounds like you are just starting out.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @BradleyDotNET!